# Who does collect TRANSACTION-ENDORSED msg, when I use Fabric CLI?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[image]
The above figure is the flow of A.

As shown in ②, the client collects the TRANSACTION-ENDORSED MSg. However, there is no client using the peer command line like "peer chaincode invoke".

Who is responsible for ② in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the SDKs. Node, Java, Go, etc. The CLI does not collect endorsements.